# Getting the jQuery Input change handler to recognize CR with no data

Tags: jquery

I have a jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/stevea/pb9MM/3/ - with an Input element.  I sense an input change with .change():

```
$(function() {
    $('input#fname').change(function(e) {
        alert("input received");
        $('div#firstName').append(this.value);
    });


});
```

I notice, though, that if I just enter Return, with no text, the change handler isn't entered. But return with no text seems to me to be a valid input .  The user is signaling you to use whatever default you have set up.  How can I call the change handler when just Return is entered?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean `Return` as in `Enter` Key? Enter key doesn't change anything in the input.. you need `keydown` handler to check the keyCode if (`e.which == 13` ) //Enter key press

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that `Return` means `Enter key`, which cannot be caught in `change` handler as it **does not change the value of the input**.

You need a `keydown` event with a condition to check if it is enter key. Something like `if (e.which == 13)`

```
$('input#fname').change(function (e) {
    alert("input received");
    $('div#firstName').append(this.value);
}).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) { //keyCode for Enter key is 13
        alert('Enter key pressed');
    }
});
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/dKJWY/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you want but if you mean to clear the value when return is pressed you shouldn't append the value but instead replace it:

```
$(function() {
    $('input#fname').change(function(e) {
        alert("input received");
        $('div#firstName').html(this.value);
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't want to clear anything.  I just want to know that the only thing the user entered was Enter.